# Which delivers better performance: Batch API or HTTP2

Tags: performance, rest, timeout

I have two web applications that sync tickets (or issues) between them.

When users create projects with 10's or 100's of tickets via App A, App A sends individual POST requests to create each corresponding ticket in App B.

When users close tickets in-mass via App B, App B sends individual POST requests to close each corresponding ticket in App A.

The above two use cases are taking a painfully long time when the ticket number exceeds 50, resulting in page timeouts for our users.

In such a scenario:

- would implementing both HTTP2 and batch API requests be superfluous? Or would implementing one solution obviate the need for the other?
- since these API's are called from within the apps' frontend (they are user-facing), would it make sense to delegate such requests to queued tasks in the background (with email notifications sent to the user once a task is completed), thus avoiding timeouts? Or would this be shying away from the optimization problem?